# Check whether a key exists or not in a scala map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I know answers are already available for similar kind of question, I tried everything but didn't work for me.

I have a map defined with key/value pair whose type is user defined. I am trying if a key exists or not after loading the map.
Below are the classes defined for key and value of the map -

```
class configKey (
      var repRole: String = "") extends Serializable {
      override def toString():String = {
        return repRole
      }
  }
    
  class configInfo (
    var modelMin: String = "",
    var modelMax: String = "",
    var delMax: String = "",
    var delAdj: String = "",
    var scrAttr: String = "") extends Serializable {
      override def toString():String = {
        return modelMin+"-"+modelMax+"-"+delMax+"-"+delAdj+"-"+scrAttr
      }
  }

  type configType  = scala.collection.mutable.Map[configKey, configInfo]
```

Below are value assignment in the map -

```
val repRole: String = "CUST EXE"
val modelMin: String = "420.0"
val modelMax: String = "490.0"
val delMax: String = "-20.0"
val delAdj: String = "400.0"
val scrAttr: String = "Zero_To_Many"

var tempConfigMap: configType = scala.collection.mutable.Map()

var confKey: configKey = new configKey()
var confInfo: configInfo = new configInfo()

confKey.repRole = repRole;
confInfo.modelMin = modelMin;
confInfo.modelMax = modelMax;
confInfo.delMax = delMax;
confInfo.delAdj = delAdj;
confInfo.scrAttr = scrAttr;

if(tempConfigMap.contains(confKey))
{                    
  tempConfigMap(confKey) = confInfo;
}
else
{                   
  tempConfigMap += confKey -> confInfo                
}
```

And at last I am checking whether the key exist or not in the map and perform the actions accordingly -

```
var AGENTROLE: String = "CUST EXE"
var configKeys: configKey = new configKey()
var configKeyDef: configKey = new configKey()
configKeys.agentRole = AGENTROLE;
configKeyDef.agentRole = "Default";

if(tempConfigMap.contains(configKeys))
  println("True")
else
  println("False")
```

In the above code, even when configKeys exists in the map, it is giving false.

I would really appreciate the help here !

Comment: The problem is probably related to the fact that normal classes are not equal by value but by reference. Thus, you must use the same value _(i.e., the same memory address)_ as before. - Overall, the whole code feels wrong and overly complicated, not sure why you need so much mutability, not sure why you use normal classes, not sure why you use `return` and `;` like this was **Java**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you defined your own custom class such as `configKey` and `configInfo`. Doing

```scala
val config1 = new configKey("rep")
val config2 = new configKey("rep")
val config3 = config1
val equals = config1 == config2 // false (equality)
val reference = config1 eq config 3 // true (reference equality)
```

As you can see, just defining a regular class, create two instances with the same constructor parameters values and compare them will return false. In this case we are talking about equality. Here you have some articles about that

- [Alvin Alexander - How to define an `equals` method in a Scala class (object equality)](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-equals-hashcode-methods-in-scala-object-equality/)

> writing an `equals` method turns out to be a difficult problem, so much so that [Programming In Scala (#ad)](https://amzn.to/2MDFczQ), Third Edition, by Odersky, Venners, and Spoon (Artima Press) takes 23 pages to discuss it, and [Effective Java (#ad)](https://amzn.to/2F0WkJE), Third Edition, by Joshua Bloch (Addison-Wesley) takes 17 pages to cover object equality. Effective Java begins its treatment with the statement, “Overriding the equals method seems simple, but there are many ways to get it wrong, and the consequences can be dire.”

- [Baelldung - Equality in scala](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/equality-in-scala)

> **Unless** we define a **case class**, where appropriate equals() and hashcode() versions are generated by the compiler, **it’s our responsibility to override them in a regular Scala class**. Otherwise, equality might not work as we would expect it to.

Working with collections (no matter if it is a list, set, dictionary, tree or any other one) using a user defined class without overriding `equals` method, will have the same problem detailed above.

```scala
val config1 = new configKey("rep")
val config2 = new configKey("rep")

List(config1).contains(config2) // false
Set(config1).contains(config2)// false
Map(config1 -> 1).contains(config2) // false (similar to your problem)
```

Once you define the equals method, you should also define the hashCode of the class. In the previous article listed they explain how to do it and why you should do it.

---

Looks like you are using scala as if you still in Java or any other language where it is common to mutate values. I suggest to consider using [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html). They already have an equals and hashcode methods already define once you compile the code and offer other features that are really useful when you only need to save values like in your example

> Case classes are like regular classes with a few key differences which we will go over. Case classes are good for modeling immutable data.

---

I would also suggest to consider to read a book such as the one mentioned in the articles shared or take a course about how to write code in scala.

It seems that you come from another stack and you are trying to use write scala code without first understand what the language can do for you. Here you have a couple of links to different learning resources

- [Alvin Alexander - functional programming simplified](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/functional-programming-simplified-book/)
- [Rúnar Bjarnason, and Paul Chiusano
  Forewords by Martin Odersky and Daniel Spiewak - Functional programming in scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala-second-edition)
- [Lightbend Academy - scala](https://academy.lightbend.com/courses/course-v1:lightbend+LSL-P-Scala-Language-Professional+v1/about)
- [Coursera - effective programming in scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/effective-scala)

Answer (score 1):

`hashcode` and `equals` should be implemented for the `Map` key type. That's not about `Scala`, that's about `JVM`. Scala's `case class` has this feature out of the box. A lot of thing can be done better, but here is a solution

```
class configKey (
  var repRole: String = "") {
  override def toString(): String = repRole
  override def hashCode(): Int = repRole.hashCode
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case k: configKeyKey => this.repRole == k.repRole
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Comment: And what if AGENTROLE is like this:


`var AGENTROLE: String = "2,CUST EXE,0,0.0,ListBuffer(),ListBuffer(),ListBuffer(),ListBuffer()"`

Comment: if it's a String -- no problems, but it's better to use case classes for keys. they have automatically generated `equals` and `hashcode` by compiler: `case class ConfigKey(repRole: String)`